# Unable to authenticate user ['elastic'] in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana

I am hitting below error in Kibana during startup via docker compose. I am using same id elastic in my kibana

below is my docker-compsoe code

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${ELASTIC_STACK_VERSION}
    environment:
       - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
       - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=changme
    volume:
........
```

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-08-14T14:11:21+00:00","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1213,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: unable to authenticate user ['elastic'] for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]"}
```

Comment: try to update kibana.yml with authentication . see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/using-kibana-with-security.html

Comment: if kibana.yml it is working fine. However in docker compose not working

Comment: environment variables can be injected into configuration using ${MY_ENV_VAR} syntax. Try to configure the kibana.yml with this pattern. elasticsearch.username:${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}. This way you can control it variables via environment variables